# Understanding pointers and variables

Tags: variables, pointers, memory-management

I was trying to understand how programs use variables and I just got to ask some thing. I am using the following snippet to explain my question.

```
int x=10;
int *p;
p=&x;       // now p stores the address of the variable x
```

Here P points to (holds the address of) **X**. And **P** itself has an address. I thought that there should be another pointer which points to this pointer. If so where is that pointer residing? Is this a file system concept? Similarly in the below case:

```
int x=10;
```

Where does our program find the address of the variable **X** so that it can access the value stored at the address referenced by **x**. Is **X** it self acting as a pointer? If so, again there should be a way to access the address of **X** which holds an address that holds an integer value **10**.

*If I am right:* for every variable declared, there is a pointer (or may be an index table) that points to the address of the variable so that we can use the value at an address referenced by the declared variable. So my question will be where is that?

*If I am wrong :* my question will be help me to understand it better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you build a program, the compiler (and in some cases the linker) replaces every variable name with either a memory address or a register.

So the executable image of your program (for example, `exe` file on Windows), does not contain any of those variables, just plain memory addresses and registers.